# Haskell String substring function

Tags: string, function, haskell, substring

My function takes 2 strings and determines if the first string is a substring of the second input string. For instance:

```
isSubb "abc" "abcmhk" -- True
isSubb "abc" "uyabcmhk" -- True
isSubb "abc" "okaibcmhk" -- False
isSubb "abc" "amnabkaaabcmhk" -- gives True
```

So far I have:

```
isSubb :: [Char] -> [Char] -> Bool
isSubb sub str = auxx sub sub str

auxx :: [Char] -> [Char] -> [Char] -> Bool
auxx safe (s:ub) (st:r)
| s:ub == []    = True
| st:r == []  = False
| s == st   = auxx safe ub r
| otherwise  = auxx safe safe r
```

But its giving me a non-exhaustive error on the `auxx` function.

Any help is greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

Comment: A bit nitpicking: you are looking for substrings (or sublists), not for subsets. Because "abc" is surely a subset of "axbycz", ins't it?

Comment: Good point. I will edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `auxx` function needs to take into account the cases where the second or the third parameters are `[]` (because you are getting there).

The `s:ub == []` and `st:r == []` will never be `True` since pattern matching happens **before** guard evaluation.

A sane equivalent of you function would be

```
auxx safe sub str
  | sub == [] = True
  | str == [] = False
  | head sub == head str = auxx safe ub r
  | otherwise = auxx safe safe r
```

Though the above is not efficient since it can be improved by pattern matching.

```
auxx _ [] _ = True
auxx _ _ [] = False
auxx safe (s:ub) (st:r)
  | s == st = auxx safe ub r
  | otherwise = auxx safe safe r
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked beautifully! i was trying to figure out something like that and didnt know you could use _

Comment: `_` stands for anything, you can place there a variable name and it will be pattern matched and bound but using `_` is desirable because no pattern match and variable binding occurs - it is simply discarded.

Answer (score 4):

In `Data.List` there is the `isInfixOF` function.

```
isInfixOf :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
```

The `isInfixOf` function takes two lists and returns `True` iff the first list is contained, wholly and intact, anywhere within the second.

```
Prelude Data.List> isInfixOf "abc" "abcmhk"
True
Prelude Data.List> isInfixOf "abc" "uyabcmhk"
True
Prelude Data.List> isInfixOf "abc" "okaibcmhk"
False
Prelude Data.List> isInfixOf "abc" "amnabkaaabcmhk"
True
```

You could write your function like

```
import Data.List (isInfixOf)

isSubb :: [Char] -> [Char] -> Bool
isSubb sub str = isInfixOf sub str
```

Answer (score -1):

Your definition is not correct!

```
 | s == st   = auxx safe ub r
```

gives problems. Look, determining whether "abc" is in "afkjskgsbc" is not the same as determining whether "bc" is in "fkjskgsbc" . So you need to consider that the first letter may or may not be a part of the string you're looking for.

Comment: This doesn't solve his error message. And, have you looked at his examples?

Comment: You're right, my answer is not helpful and he already has a right test case to check for. Sorry!

Comment: Also what you say is the problem in your answer is not a problem. Look at the `otherwise` branch